USB DAC stops after upgrade to 24.04
For approximately 6 months I have been using a Dell i3 based desktop PC running Ubuntu 22.04 to play music to an integrated amplifier (Rotel A14 MKII) via a USB 2.0 connection. To play music I am using MPD and ALSA. This has been working flawlessly.
After recently upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04  the music output now stops after what seems to be a random amount of time; sometimes after 20 seconds, sometimes after a few minutes. To resume I need to disconnect theamplifier/DAC a few seconds, then stop and restart the player, however it will fail again. When the music stops, there is no indication in the player, and so far i cannot/find any related log entries.
I also have a stand-alone desktop DAC, a Topping E30II, so connected that to see if it has the same problem, and it does 'not'. However I accidentally discovered something very interesting about the problem.....
The Topping E30II DAC requires a 5VDC power supply, and comes with 2 cables; the power cable is designed to plug in to a USB A power supply and I was using a second USB A port on the PC to power it. After i tested the E30, I removed the DAC USB cable but left the USB 'power' cable for the E30 connected. Then when i reconnected my integrated amplifier, it works flawless again, I tested many times for periods of 30-40 minutes. However if I unplug the E30's 'power' cable from the USB port of the PC, the music will again stop after 20 sec etc.
I have disabled the USB auto suspend (usbcore.autosuspend=-1 in /etc/default/grub) but problem persists. I also tried plugging in an external USB HDD but problem persists.
When the E30 is connected only for power, it does not appear as a device in either ALSA of Pulseaudio.
Any suggestions on how to fix this problem, or how I can at least find some indication of why the music stops (some log or device status)?

i believe problem is resolved though not exactly sure what fixed it.
I got the idea to try connecting integrated amp to front USB ports and when i did, music no longer stopped unexpectedly.  However, when i tried to confirm this was a solution, and moved back to rear USB connection, the problem did not return.
I am concluding with some doubt, that the problem was actually resolved when I disabled the USB auto suspend, and that i must not have powered down the computer sufficiently for this to take effect when i originally tested this.
